# Python - math.prod()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
for x in range(13):
   prod(random.SystemRandom().random() for x in range(8))
```

What exactly does the "for x in range(8)" do in the prod function? I've read the math documentation but I still don't get it. Can someone explain this function?

Comment: It generates a sequence of eight `random.SystemRandom().random()` values, and passes that sequence as the argument to `prod()`.

Comment: That's a generator expression. It generates 8 random numbers, which are passed as arguments to `prod()`. Then `prod()` multiplies them.

Comment: @Barmar: It's maybe worth noting that *the whole generator expression* is the single argument to `prod`. It's not passing eight separate arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for x in range(8)` is just part of a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), it has nothing to do with `math.prod`. To answer your question, it creates a sequence of eight random numbers on the interval [0, 1]. You may see this by

```py
import random

list(random.SystemRandom().random() for x in range(8))
```

```
[0.003455723936271693, 0.6805747786326888, 0.546261218098562, 0.601146820744067, 0.8435991971789742, 0.9648570965040333, 0.28307143225490927, 0.4388989719001757]
```

Using the variable name `x` is bad practice here because it shadows the `x` in `for x in range(13)`. The established convention for an unused variable is to name it `_`. A better implementation of this code is:

```py
from math import prod
import random

for x in range(13):
    prod(random.SystemRandom().random() for _ in range(8))
```

Comment: Note that there is a missing `)` at the end of the last line. It's in the markdown but for some reason isn't rendering. I tried a bunch of hacky things to get it to render but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Thanks @Blckknght for the edit. I still don't see the difference in the source but I'm much obliged.

Answer (score 4):

This is nothing specific to `math.prod()`.  That's a generator expression that produces a sequence of random numbers. It produces 8 of them because of `for x in range(8)`.

The argument to `math.prod()` is an iterable, and a generator is one type of iterable. `prod()` multiplies all the values in the iterable sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you asking about the syntax or step through.

The range function returns a sequence of numbers starting at 0 going up to to the input you specify.

As this is written it will take the product of 9 random numbers between 0 and 1.

```
prod(random.SystemRandom().random() for x in range(8))
```

Because you have it in a loop (for x in range(13)) it will do this 14 times.

```
for x in range(13):
   prod(random.SystemRandom().random() for x in range(8))
```

If your question is about list comprehension you can read about it in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).